# TeXmaker as default application to open tex files

Tags: 16.04, latex, default-programs

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I would like to have TeXmaker as the default application to open tex files. Right now, if I double-click a -tex file, gedit will open it instead.

If I do
right click on the file -> properties -> open with -> show other applications

I find that TeXmaker is not in the list.

However, Texmaker is properly installed and running properly, for example if I first lauch it and then open a -tex file from inside TeXmaker itself.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can not associate from GUI - you may try to set tex-file association in configuration file *~/.config/mimeapps.list*     .

Add (or change existing) line

```
text/x-tex=texmaker.desktop;
```

to the section

```
[Added Associations]
```

Comment: Where fo I find this config folder?

Comment: As you may know `~` is your home folder (for example `/home/federico`). So the full path is `/home/federico/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Answer (score 3):

Open properties for any .txt file.  Select "Open With", "Texmaker".  Select "Make Default".  This will make Texmaker the default for all text files.