# Set priorities for file-open applications

Tags: nautilus, default-programs, mime-type

Most of the time I open .sla scribus files ("application/vnd.scribus" mimetype) with Scribus application, but sometimes I have to edit them with Geany (.SLA files are a kind of flat XML files). I do find Geany in the rightclick > other apps menu. Fine.

BUT after editing a .SLA with Geany once, Geany is set to be the new default application. I don't want this.

How can I set Scribus to be the real and only default application to open .SLA files and never have Geany replace it?

I've searched and tried various threads, but I could not find any applicable answers.

The OS is Ubuntu 18.04.01 (Bionic Beaver).

Answer (score 0):

I found out!

- Edit as root the `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` file that actually links to `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`
- Add the relevant priority association:

  ```
  application/vnd.scribus=scribus-trunk.desktop
  ```
- Save

That's it.

Scribus is now *always* the default application. Geany appears fine in the "other application" menu.

Comment: It is a bad idea to change system-wide configuration files. You can loose this setting after accentally upgraded `desktop-file-utils` package (has `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` inside). The better way is to edit current user config (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1015601/66509) as reference).

Comment: Nope @N0rbert, your proposal is not a solution, because `~/.config/mimeapps.list` is also renewed everytime i use a new application from the "other apps menu" : when i choose `geany` instead of scribus, geany is written first in the possible apps for .SLA files, and it becomes the default application ! This is just what i wanted to avoid, and why i created this new question.

Comment: BTW @N0rbert it's a pain when `desktop-file-utils` resets `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` when upgraded. Is there a design flaw somewhere around this issue or a bug maybe ?

Comment: *1.* Understood and agreed with you about mimeapps.list. *2.* It is not a bug. It is main concept of [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(Debian)). But we can believe that it will not upgrade often :)